# Opera PMS v5.0 record locked by another user?how to fix it

Tags: mysql

May I know why I cannot edit user account even I using supervisor account it show up record locked by another user. How to fix it?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to Utilities. Under Tools > Session control, you can look for the user by PMS username and kill session there.